# Strange emails in postfix queue

Tags: email, spam-prevention, postfix, spamassassin

Currently I am not sending any emails, I have postfix and dovecot installed but in the in the postfix mail queue I see strange emails almost every minute, i dont know from where is this spam generating and how to stop it:

From: test@test.com 
To: some strange italian emails

Here is the header of one of the emails:

```
Received    from User (localhost [127.0.0.1])   by mydomain.com (Postfix) with SMTP id 0F0BD25300245;   Mon, 14 Jul 2014 18:01:40 +0200 (CEST)
From    "BancoPopolare"<test@test.com>
Subject BGDNGHYSIC
Date    Mon, 14 Jul 2014 18.00.02 +0200
MIME-Version    1.0
Content-Type    multipart/mixed;    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0078_01C2AA85.50C60CC8"
X-Priority  3
X-MSMail-Priority   Normal
X-Mailer    Microsoft Outlook Express 6.00.2800.1081
X-MimeOLE   Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.00.2800.1081
Message-Id  <20140714160141.0F0BD25300245@githoster.com>
To  undisclosed-recipients:;
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, I needed to add this to my config file:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    permit
```